# Cold water only dribbling from faucet

Tags: water-pressure

i have a cascade style (water runs over top of faucet) faucet in bathroom. It's only a few months old and cold water was fine at beginning but has gone down to a dribble. Other cold taps are okay. Can not block the flow to force the hot into cold line to eliminate possible air locks because of style of faucet. Any idea? Thank you! Don

Comment: Turn of the valve under the sink, remove the hose from the valve to the faucet and check for water flow by opening the valve (use another hose and bucket.) Good flow? Then you have something plugging the waterway from the valve, in the hose or the faucet itself.

Comment: Jeff this should be an answer.

Comment: For some reason my Android devices like to comment more than answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Turn of the valve under the sink, remove the hose from the valve to the faucet and check for water flow by opening the valve (use another hose and bucket.) Good flow? Then you have something plugging the waterway from the valve, in the hose or the faucet itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a new government mandated faucet that saves the planet by reducing water flow to a dribble.  :-)

See if there's any kind of aerator (like a screen) or flow restrictor (like a small hole in a filler plate) located somewhere inside the faucet behind the opening.  They can catch debris.  As the water runs, it collects the debris and holds it against the screen or hole.  If there is one, you will need to figure out how to remove or get behind it to clean it out.